# Правильно ли я разобрал предложение?

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте. Только что разобрал предложение, а точнее, просто выделил грамматические основы и второстепенные члены предложения. Пожалуйста, проверьте, правильно ли я сделал это.

Правильно ли я поставил запятую перед **и**? Спасибо.

P.S. Вот ссылка на фотографию: http://uploads.ru/N8iZF.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятая нужна, так как она разделяет две части сложного предложения: музыка понравилась, я загрузил. А вот в разборе по членам предложения есть ошибка. : загрузил на что? - на плеер (дополнение), плеер чей? - свой (определение). Даже если поставить вопрос "куда?" - "на плеер", обстоятельством будут только слова "на плеер", а "свой" - это определение

Comment: Разбирая предложение, я размышлял так: "Загрузил куда? на плеер". Тут ведь все-таки обстоятельство. Или я все же ошибаюсь?

Answer (score 0):

"Музыка мне очень понравилась, и я загрузил ее на свой плеер".Это ССП, состоящее из двух простых предложений. Сложный и спорный момент данного разбора - это определение роли падежной формы "на плеер".

РЕШЕНИЕ

Если можно задать два вопроса (на что? и куда?), то такую падежную форму лучше считать ДОПОЛНЕНИЕМ с добавочным обстоятельственным значением.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

1) Когда падежная форма является только обстоятельством

Обычно обстоятельство места обозначает место, взаимное расположение, направление движения, например: идти к лесу, рядом с домом, вдоль дороги.  В этом случае существительное близко по значению к НАРЕЧИЮ и задает КООРДИНАТЫ МЕСТА, но в действии не участвует.

2) В нашем случае предмет участвует в действии (на него распространяется действие), но в то же время он задает и направление действия.